# Call function when d3 add method will finish execution

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a circle and text in a group element.

```
var textInMainNode = mainNodeGroup
    .selectAll('foreignObject')
    .data(mainNodeObject)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.radius * 2;})
    .attr('height', function(d) {return d.radius * 2;})
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id', 'main-node-text-wrap')
    .html(function (d) { return '<p id="main-node-text">'+d.label+'</p>'; 
});
```

This is the code which adds text element (html in foreignObject) to the circle.

Right after that I call this code:

```
console.log($('#main-node-text').height());
```

Which returns value of 32. The real height of 'main-node-text' is 64 pixels.

If I call the same function with timeout of 100 milliseconds - then it returns correct value of 32 pixels.

**Question**: How can I be sure that rendering of elements are done and execute my code after that?

**EDIT** As long as question is not solved, please, answer.
I tried to put fixed height of 64 px to 'main-node-text' and it works, but when height is auto, then height of 'p' element changes after some time.

**EDIT 2** This is the live page: [HERE](http://tuko.me/)

**Answer is in comments below the right answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.append` is, as any other DOM manipulation, synchronous. That means it is finished as soon it returns and therefore you will have the `height` available on the next line, without delays. You probably have an error somewhere else in the code, as the following snippet, based on your code, works:

```js
var mainNodeObject = [{radius: 10, label: "Hello"}];
var textInMainNode = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .selectAll('foreignObject')
    .data(mainNodeObject)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.radius * 2;})
    .attr('height', function(d) {return d.radius * 2;})
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id', 'main-node-text-wrap')
    .html(function (d) { return '<p id="main-node-text">'+d.label+'</p>'; 
});

alert($('#main-node-text').height());
```

```css
#main-node-text {
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'd be careful about setting the `id` attribute. By definition, it should be present at most **once per page**. Since you're assigning it for every element of the `mainNodeObject` array, it's probably being present multiple times. That can lead to problems with selector matching, both in CSS and in jQuery. Try using `class` attribute and `.` selector (e.g. `.attr('class', 'main-node-text')` and `.main-node-text` selector).

Also check if you're not running any `transition`'s or if you're not changing the DOM in response to AJAX requests.

Comment: thanks for the fast answering. I know that id must specify only one element per page and I have only one element with the id on the page. I just do not know how to add only one element with object specified via d3. Found only this solution.

Comment: what about the element's height. I have not specified in css the height of the "main-node-text" so it changes depending on text. May be here is the problem?

Comment: No, unless there are async elements (e.g. images) being loaded in the `d.label`, the element won't change its `height` after the script's execution. If there are images, you should specify their dimensions - `<img height='...' width='...'>`. As for the single-element insert, you can drop the `.selectAll()`, `.data()` and `.enter()` lines and instead put `.datum(mainNodeObject[0])` after the `.append()` line.

Comment: thanks for the information provided, very useful. Will try to make some changes.

Comment: Your code works because you specified in css width and height of the 'p' tag.

Comment: @eatmypants I'm now looking at your code and even there I can't replicate your behavior, I'm getting 68px in the console the first time, both in Chrome and Firefox on Windows. My guess however would be that you're running into a race condition, that your browser delays the font loading and displaying until after your script has run. Therefore, your script runs, one-lined label appears at ~30px, then the bigger Open Sans font loads and the text gets wrapped to ~65px. As to how to fix that, please provide the browser you're using. This should be happening,  and on most browsers it isn't.

Comment: I tried chrome and firefox too. Firefox makes rendering slowly and i get value of 20px everytime. I tested the page on laptop and pc - they have the same behaviour. I tried to remove open sans font - eveything stayed the same.

Comment: So I found the problem. It was it html file in which I connected scripts with 'defer' parameter. I thought it means, that scripts should be uploaded it this order, which they go...